# Delete NA values from a data frame with R

Tags: r

I have a large scale data frame with ?_? values which dimensions are 501 rows and 42844 columns. Using R , i have already replaced them with NA by using this code below :

```
data[data == "?_?"] <- NA
```

So i have NA values now and I want to omit these from the Data.frame but something is going bad....
When I hit the command below :

```
data_na_rm <- na.omit(data)
```

I get a 0 , 42844 object as a result.

```
dim(data_na_rm) #gives me 0 42844
data_na_rm[1,2] #gives me NA
data_na_rm[5,3] #gives me NA
############################
data_na_rm[2]   #gives me the title of the second column 
data_na_rm[5]   #gives me the title fo the fifth
```

What i have to do?? I've spend on this thing to many hours. I would appreciate if anyone could spend some time for this in order to help me.

Comment: `na.omit` will drop all rows that have any `NA`s anywhere in the row.  You probably have some `NA`s  in every row somewhere

Comment: `data[data == "?_?"] <- NA` ... this looks strange to me.  Wasn't your intention to replace values in a single _column_?

Comment: First of all i want to thank everyone who have spend time for me and my develop issue.Tim Biegeleisen my intention was to replace the `?_?` values with `NA` everywhere in the data_frame. I want to run a Bayesian model with Bugs on this data_set, so in order to work with Bugs/R_Jugs I have to replace these values with NA first and then omit them. Nonetheless i haven't thought that maybe this Data_frame includes at least one NA value in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what JackStat said in the comments, you might have NAs in every row. Maybe you should test for that?:

```
    # Some Data. All rows have an NA but not all columns

    df <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4),
             col2 = c(1, NA, 3, 4),
             col3 = c(1, 2, NA, 4),
             col4 = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
             col5 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

# test whether an NA is present in each row

apply(df, 1, function(x) {sum(is.na(x)) > 0})
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This will help you find which columns are contributing the most NAs. It sums up the number of NAs:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))})
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
   1    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: Oh my god!!!! I have at least one NA value in each row... You have right William and thank you very much for your help. I must search now for what i have to do in order to handle this data.frame in order to run a bayesian model on R_Jugs.

Comment: @GiorgosK Glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: @GiorgosK I added an update that might help you find if there are certain columns that are contributing a large number of NAs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've already checked it that way but it is quite more complicated.... This data-set includes SNIPs in other words genotypes ex(AA AB BB).I don't care about columns... note that each line contains the unique genotype of an animal. So i can't erase columns because the genotype sequence wil change. Anyway... thank you very much...

Comment: @GiorgosK No problem. Good luck with everything!